# Asp.Net Core render ViewComponent to variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to render `ViewComponent` to a string in a service in ASP.NET Core 3.0 (Pages).

I found two partial solutions to my problem, but both are for older pre 3.0 version and have some issues that I do not know how to resolve.

- First one is taken from [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/pauldotknopf/b424e9b8b03d31d67f3cce59f09ab17f), but designed with controllers in mind and `NullView` was removed 3.0 (and is really hard to find any reference on it).
- The second option is [here](https://ppolyzos.com/2016/09/09/asp-net-core-render-view-to-string/), but fails one line 42 (no view is found). I believe that this is due to the changes made in .net core, where the views are now precompiled and the razor view engine therefore cannot find them.

I did some of my own experimenting, but could not get it working (I believe I am facing the same issue as the second solution I posted). I would appreciate any help regarding this matter on how to get it working. I've added my best attempt and a minimum project to [GitHub](https://github.com/jakakonda/View2String), where Render is in the Service folder and in the Index.cshtml.cs is the call to the service.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### The Reasons

1. [`NullView`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/0fd9f27d60f727ad9b769f72de5dfae8f840a456/src/Mvc/Mvc.ViewFeatures/src/NullView.cs#L11-L26) is an internal class now. But that's a very simple class that does nothing. In other words, simply copy & paste it from the src into your source code.
2. The tutorials you linked above is used to render a plain view. However, since you're trying to render a view component instead of a view, you should avoid [passing a view path directly](https://github.com/jakakonda/View2String/blob/43e8bf3b33f8966359306c12a1c0ff64919bc62d/View2String/Pages/Index.cshtml.cs#L20). You should pass a **ViewComponent Class Name** (or **Type**) instead.

   ```
   Model = await _viewRender.RenderToStringAsync(
       "/Components/Test/Default.cshtml", // don't pass a view path since we're not rendering a view file but a view component
       "Test",                            // because the `ViewComponent` Name is Test
       new TestModel { StrToPrint = "Print From Service" });
   ```
3. According to the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-3.1#view-search-path), 
   The runtime **searches for the view in the following paths**:

   > 1. /Views/{Controller Name}/Components/{View Component Name}/{View Name}
   > 2. /Views/Shared/Components/{View Component Name}/{View Name}
   > 3. /Pages/Shared/Components/{View Component Name}/{View Name}

   However, your `Test` ViewComponent resides in `Pages/Components/Test/Default.cshtml`, **which can not be found by Razor by default**. Either configure a custom View Location, or move it to the standard location such that Razor can find the view files.
4. Finally, [rendering a ViewComponent as a page](https://github.com/jakakonda/View2String/blob/43e8bf3b33f8966359306c12a1c0ff64919bc62d/View2String/Services/ViewRendererService.cs#L93) seems a bit of overkill. I would suggest you should  use `IViewComponentHelper` to render the `ViewComponent` as an `IHtmlContent` such that I can write to a `StringWriter`:

   ```
   public class MyViewComponentContext 
   {
       public HttpContext HttpContext { get; set; }
       public ActionContext ActionContext { get; set; }
       public ViewDataDictionary ViewData { get; set; }
       public ITempDataDictionary TempData { get; set; }
   }
   private async Task<string> Render( MyViewComponentContext myViewComponentContext,string viewComponentName,object args) {
       using (var writer = new StringWriter())
       { 
           var helper = this.GetViewComponentHelper(myViewComponentContext, writer);
           var result = await helper.InvokeAsync(viewComponentName, args);  // get an IHtmlContent
           result.WriteTo(writer, HtmlEncoder.Default);
           await writer.FlushAsync();
           return writer.ToString();
       }
   }
   ```

#### Demo

If I fix the issues as I described above, when running your project I'll get the correct result:

[image]