# Generate Razor page from string to string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor

I'm trying to render a Razor page from a string so that the output is also a string.

Generally I would like store pages in database in Razor Page fromat because I have buissness case that the user could have a own custom template and he could use a few built in custom tags in the template. Is it possible to do something like that?

I know that there is something like RazorEngine but this library is not longer supported. So I was looking in build-in ViewContext but I see that it only support for build-in pages...

Comment: That is not possible.  Razor pages are a pre-packaged model-view-controller architecture (controller outputs Page Model, which is then rendered using the .cshtml file as a sort of template) that outputs HTML.  The controller/model/view are created then built, then rendered at run-time.  (You can't really do all of that at run-time.... the build will be fixed before run-time happens.)  You might want to layout all your requirements in more detail to get suggestions on what might be possible.

Comment: Do you want to render A Partial View To A String ? Have you check  this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63297920/programmatically-render-razor-page-as-html-string?

Comment: @pcalkins do you have any idea how can I achieve something like that? the most important stuff for me are custom tags

Comment: @QingGuo I saw that but unfortunately this isn't that what I want to achieve